# why is this azure apim policy expression failing?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I've written a simple policy expression for Azure APIM which includes a code block expression.  This works:

@{ return "start" + new Random().Next().ToString(); }

However, this does not work:

@{ return "start" + new Random().Next().ToString() + "end" }

I tried several variations of the second example but was unable to get the APIM policy manager to accept it. The APIM policy error returns the following error:

"Error in element 'log-to-eventhub' on line 1, column 21: Code block expression must be enclosed in curly brackets."

However, the expression above *is* in curly brackets.  Any idea how I can achieve what I'm trying to do in the second example above?

Comment: Coding `new Random().Next()` is going to cause you duplicate values if that code runs in a tight loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rewriting it as (note semicolon at the end):

```
@{ return "start" + new Random().Next().ToString() + "end"; }
```

or (without "return"):

```
@{ "start" + new Random().Next().ToString() + "end" }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also just use a single statement expression and the snazzy new c# 6 string interpolation

```
@($"start {new Random().Next().ToString()} end")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ;(semicolon) at the end .

```
@{ return "start" + new Random().Next().ToString() + "end"; }
```